# Emailing data of multiple html form fields using python flask_mail msg.body=""

Tags: python, html, forms, email, flask

What I'm trying to do is send an email when the user submits the html form in index.html using flask_mail. I want to send multiple form fields in msg body. How do I do that? I have researched the flask_mail documentation thoroughly but didn't find the answer.
There are no errors if I try to send simple msg in msg.body="hello" but gives error when I try to send form data.

And yes I don't want to use flask templates.

First I execute the app.py using "python -m flask run" and then I go to index.html to fill the form and submit.

Both index.html and app.py are in different folders.

I also want to read data from checkboxes, radiobuttons,dropdownlist, and uploaded files. So how to do that and send all that values to admin using flask_mail.

This is my form in index.html. In the action parameter I have specified the below url.

```
 <form class="" action=" http://127.0.0.1:5000/" id="get-quote" name="get-quote" method="post">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <!-- Text input-->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class=" form-group ">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                                                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required>
                                                <span class="help-block"> </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Text input-->
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group ">
                                                <label class=" control-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
                                                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control input-md">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Text input-->
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group ">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
                                                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group slide-ranger ">

                                                <label for="amount" class="control-label">Loan Amount</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"placeholder="Enter your amount" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group slide-ranger ">

                                                <label for="years" class="control-label">Year</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="years" name="years" placeholder="Enter number of years(eg:1,2,3)" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Button -->
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <button id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit New Quote</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
```

This is my app.py in flask_mail

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from flask import request, redirect

app =Flask(__name__)
mail=Mail(app)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'mymail@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'my_password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def index():
   name = request.form['name']
   email = request.form['email']
   phone = request.form['phone']
   amount = request.form['amount']
   years = request.form['years']
   msg = Message('Get-Quote Form', sender = 'mymail@gmail.com', recipients = ['mymail@gmail.com'])
   msg.body = "I want all the above field here to send mail."
   mail.send(msg)
   return "Sent"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: welcome, what does the error say when you try to set msg.body and send it?

Comment: @shiny it says Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved as following:

```
msg.body = 'Name is: {} \n Email is: {} \n and Phone is: {} \n Amount:{} \n Years:{}'.format(name,email,phone,amount,years)
```

Answer (score 0):

so you are visiting your index page, where the form is? If so, you will need to change methods to `['POST', 'GET']`, also make an if statement if the request is POST or GET. Check the WTForms docs for reference: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/

Comment: Okay will try that. But can you tell how do I pass multiple fileds or arguments in the msg.body="Name: ' "+name+" '" "Email: ' "+email+" '"  . Is this correct??

Comment: i would suggest to use basic formating: `"""{name} ({email}) phone: {phonenumber}""".format(name=name, email=email, phonenumber=phone)` This way you can use plain text email and insert line breaks. the .format makes it easier to format your string the right way. Check the docs here: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Thank you! @shiny